# Top line on page is missing

Tags: bug, user-interface

On the Mi Yodeya page there is usually a line at the top where I can see my name and reputation points and badges, and also links to chat, review and meta.  Right now, its gone.  Also lost is my ability to type in a few letters and obtain tag suggestions.  I had that promblem a few months ago. Finally, the site is asking me if I'm human and having me type in some random letters.  I wasn't getting that for months.  Did something change and I missed it?  Or does my computer have a communications issue with the website?  I think, but I'm not sure, that I'm on using Internet Explorer 7 and operating on Windows 7.

Comment: Can you include some technical data? (e.g. browser type)

Comment: Related? : http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1319

Comment: Bruce, just checking, but are you logged in?  (I assume if you're posting on meta the answer is yes, but the captcha makes me suspicious.)  Also, does it look like the screen shot in the question msh210 linked?  Finally, browser & version, OS, and window size (<1024px wide?) would help.  Thanks.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Windows 7, window size is 1024 wide.  Brower, I think, is IE7.  I appear to be looged on.  No problem with Meta's tags appearing.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'm also having trouble with the messages link.  It is not responding.

Comment: Note, we only support IE9+, however disabling compatibility mode does cure many issues with IE7 and 8 (if you're forced to use those), at least for now, but probably won't in the coming future.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem also. Make sure you are not in compatibility mode. Then everything should be fixed.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: @BruceJames Here is a [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/f4wdv71qr/). Make sure that the circled button is not pressed.

Comment: @BruceJames Let me know if that works.